# PHP 5 HTML 5 contact form

Tags: php, html

I am very new to website design/programming and learned allot of html, css and a bit of php over the past few weeks. This is my first post here, Wish me luck :)

I am attempting to create a mail form from what I have learned from various websites, the form works but I have an issue with sanitizing the input, I'm not sure if I am doing it correctly as I can still "inject" code into the fields.

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php
     $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

     $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $error = '';

     // Name
     $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

     // Telephone Number
     $phone= filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

     // Email Address
     $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
     if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $error = 'You have not entered a valid email address.<br/>';
    }

     // Message
     $message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

     if (empty($error)) {
     $from = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>'; 
     $to = 'YourEmailHere';
     $subject = 'Message from Contact Form';
     $content = $name . ' has sent you a message: \n' . $message . '\n\nPhone Number: ' . $phone . '\n\nIP: ' . $ip . '\nBrowser:' . $browser;
     $success = '<h3>Thank you!<br /> Your message has been sent!</h3>';
     //mail($to,$subject,$content,$from);
     }
     }
    ?>
    <h1>Contact Form</h1>
    <br/>
    <?php
       if (!empty($error)) {
       echo '<p class="error"><strong>Your message was NOT sent<br/> The following error(s) returned:</strong><br/><br/>' . $error . '<br/><strong>Please try again.</strong><br/></p>';
       } elseif (!empty($success)) {
       echo $success;
       }
    ?>
      <form action="" method="post">
         Name:
         <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Name" value="<?php { echo $_POST['name']; } ?>"><br/>
         Telephone:
         <input type="text" name="phone" required placeholder="Telephone Number e.g.0123456789" value="<?php { echo $_POST['phone']; } ?>"><br/>
         Email:
         <input type="text" name="email" required placeholder="Email Address" value="<?php { echo $_POST['email']; } ?>"><br/>
         Message:<br />
         <textarea name="message" required placeholder="Message" rows="20" cols="20"><?php { echo $_POST['message']; } ?></textarea><br/>
         <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Send message">
         <br/>
       </form>
       <!-- Below is Just for testing  -->
       <?php     echo '<br/>Name : ' . $name . '<br/><br/>Phone : ' . $phone . '<br/><br/>Email : ' . $email . '<br/><br/>Message : ' . $message . '<br/>'; ?>
   <br/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I'll add layout/css later once I get the code working the way I would like.
any assistance will be most appreciated.

The "injection" code I am testing with is simply

```
    "><script>alert('Broke');</script>
```

the sanitize works fine if I leave out the leading ">, even just using the "> alone messes up and page a little, I would like to know if there is a way to filter these just using options available in php.
Once I get input into this simple form working correctly I plan to use  database functionality on the rest of the site so it is important to me that I get a good understanding of filtering for obvious reasons.

Thanks in Advance.

Aaron

Another Question, as you can see from the code I display an error if the email address is not valid according to the FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, how would I go about doing this on the other fields (Name[text only], Telephone Number[10 digit telephone number] and Message[text with punctuation]) ?

I am also looking to add captcha script, a simple "random number [random calculation type +-X/] random number = answer" with the random numbers and calculation type displayed as an image, not sure where to start with this or if it would be too complicated for visitors.

Comment: Try `htmlspecialchars($stringHere)`

Comment: Also you seem to be wrapping your echoes in curly braces - they are not needed. You can in fact do this: `<?=$_POST['message']?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing some basic sanitising and validation but then proceeding to echo the raw (un-sanitised data) back to the client within the form.

```
<?php { echo $_POST['email']; } ?>
```

Change your value outputs to check for the sanitised values and output them appropriately.

```
<?php echo (isset($email) ? $email : ''); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing the `$_POST` variables without sanitising them.

Wrap them in `htmlspecialchars()` like this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
```